# Set JWT access token

Tags: reactjs, django

which one is better and why :
set JWT token in request headers by **frontend** developers
or set in cookie by **backend** developers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, it's recommended for the token not be accessed by client applications directly as it leaves it vulnerable to many client side attacks, like XSS and etc. HTTPS cookies are considered the secure option when handling tokens between server and client (XSRF is usually considered less of a problem to deal with). There are some catches, like maximum size of a cookie, client support, but it shouldn't be an issue in most cases. For more information about vulnerabilities and how to deal with them, checkout the OWASP cheat sheet: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: So in conclusion, you're saying token should be stored the in back end with pre-defined domain or in front end (client side) by customizing the cookies?

Comment: The token should be set in the HTTPS (Secure) Cookie in the backend (BE) side, you cannot create Secure and HTTP Cookie in frontend. The whole point of a HTTP and Secure cookie is that the client (for ex. Browser) wouldn't be able to access its content (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#security), but for each request from the client, the BE will be able to securely check the secure cookies value to verify the token in it.